# Angular UI Bootstrap tabset + ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have trouble setting up a tabset with dynamic contents using ng-include.
I tried unsuccessfully with ng-repeat :

```
<tabset justified="true">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{ tab.heading }}" active="tab.active">
         <div ng-include="tab.template"></div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Also, I tried without the ng-repeat :

```
<tabset justified="true">
    <tab heading="{{ tabs.1.heading }}" active="tabs.1.active">
         <div ng-include="'partial/profile/template1.html'"></div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="{{ tabs.2.heading }}" active="tabs.2.active">
         <div ng-include="'partial/profile/template2.html'"></div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="{{ tabs.3.heading }}" active="tabs.3.active">
         <div ng-include="'partial/profile/template3.html'"></div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="{{ tabs.4.heading }}" active="tabs.4.active">
         <div ng-include="'partial/profile/template4.html'"></div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="{{ tabs.5.heading }}" active="tabs.5.active">
         <div ng-include="'partial/profile/template5.html'"></div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Yet, what I get is a blanck page, not responding and those errors :

```
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

and

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

FYI: the templates are mainly empty, the one not empty contain a basic table.
How am I to make it work ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide plnkr?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/g3bI4HjXW2Qtg1wHhsA6

I can't make it work on plunker, but it's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you had extra quotes when using `ng-repeat`. The extra quotes in `ng-include="'x.html'"` are only needed if it's used as an attribute.

When specifying it as a variable in JavaScript, you set the scope variable in JavaScript as follows: `$scope.someTemplateUrl = "x.html";` then set the attribute to `ng-include="someTemplateUrl"`. Notice the value of the variable doesn't contain the single quotes.

And the second version you should be doing `tab[0].heading` rather than `tab.0.heading` (and starting from 0 rather than 1).

I've created a Plunker containing a working version and it seems to work correctly:

http://plnkr.co/edit/cL9RPB4otw57pORJqjvx?p=preview

What I did:

- removed the extra quotes from the template property
- removed html5Mode because Plunker doesn't work with that.

So something like:

```
$scope.tabs = [
        {
            "heading": "Tab 1",
            "active": true,
            "template":"tab1.html"
        },
        ...
```